# how to slickslice many folder script shell?

Tags: shell

I use slickslice to make screenshot of my video
I just want to automate the processus
So i i do that :

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in *.mp4; do slickslice -x $f -w 720; done
mkdir screen
mv *.jpg screen
```

In a folder i slickslice all the file and i move them in a folder call screen.

Now i want to do that in a folder with many other folder.
For exemple they are many folder (each with a film name).
I want the script enter the first folder make the slickslice get out and enter in the next foder and this for every folder.
How to ?
Do you understand what i want ?

Thanks a lot guys

Comment: use `find . -type f -name '*.mp4'`

Comment: @FredrikPihl, ...`find . -type f -name '*.mp4' -exec slickslice -x {} -w 720 \;` -- worth including the details. If instead one ran `for f in $(find . -type f -name '*.mp4')`, for instance, that would be *far* less reliable.

Comment: i use find . -type f -name '*.mp4' -exec slickslice -x {} -w 720 \;
and it work really great thanks

Comment: But i got question why do you use a "." ? Does it work wihout ?

Comment: can i do find . -type f -name '*.mp4' -exec slickslice -x {} -w 720 >/dev/null \;